# Only animate list items when new are inserted, not when mounting initial

Tags: reactjs

I have a `ListView` component, which is a live-updating feed, rendering a collection of child component `ListItem`.

Each time a new `ListItem` is added, I want to add a transition animation.

Problem is, I don't know how to accomplish this without applying the transition on the initial load. The list often have 30+ elements initially, these should not be animated.

I tried setting a 'initialLoad' state, and doing something with `transitionEnter={!initialLoad}` but this ended up being messy

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You shold add new `ListItem` with some sub-class like `ListItem animated`, and assign css transitions or jquery animation by this sub-class

Comment: Have you looked at reacts CSS transitions? https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html This includes option to not animate on initial mount.